# Help needed with soldering SPI flash (MX25L8006E)

Tags: soldering

Ok so I want to first remove a SPI flash ([MX25L8006E](http://www.macronix.com/en-us/Product/Pages/ProductDetail.aspx?PartNo=MX25L8006E)) from the pcb and then after modifying its content using Arduino put it back on.

How to do this safe? First on I only have a soldiering iron (30W) (of-course I also have tinol and rosin flux).

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSzfNrbDfIY) but I'm not sure if it's safe judging by the comments.

What I'm worrying about is that the temperature range specified on the site for the chip is -40℃ to +85℃ but I've looked up the soldering temperature is way higher (315C). And I don't want to brake the chip.

Any advice?

Foot note : I'm a total noob at soldering. My only experience with it was making my old PS2 unusable by trying to install some hack-chip on it. So sorry if the question is stupid for you.

Answer (score 1):

All soldering profiles are high temperatures. A typical [reflow profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflow_soldering) will peak at about 210C (leaded) or 250C (lead free). There is no guidance on hand soldering (the usual guidance is 300C, 10 to 30 seconds).

The maximum rating in the datasheet is not the soldering profile; it is the maximum temperature where normal operation is *guaranteed*. Note that the storage temperature (not in use) is -65C to +150C.

There is no guidance in the datasheet for the specifics of the reflow profile either. I searched the manufacturers site for soldering guidance and there was no results.

You do not state which package you have (there are 5) as some packages are more amenable to removal with a good chance of not destroying the device than others.

So you do not need to worry about the 85C; what you *do* need to worry about is whether hand soldering is appropriate.

Comment: It should be 8-PIN SOP (I'm not sure how to tell if it's 200mil or 150mil though). I'm judging by the pin configuration in the data-sheet as mine chip isn't cut on the one side and it also has a dot on it.

Answer (score 1):

ICs are designed to survive at least one SMD soldering cycle, but I simply don't believe that you will be able to unsolder an SMD IC with a 30W hand iron and then expect it to work when you're done.  I know this isn't the answer you want to hear, but my best advise is to MAKE OTHER PLANS.

Either rework your system so you can alter the memory in-circuit, flash your brand-spanking new memory off the board before you mount it, or build some sort of adapter board that is easy to remove, maybe with a connector, and program the memory on that.  In any case, count on tossing the IC after desoldering.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Why would soldering a new memory work but desoldering the old one will destroy it? You know even when soldering a new one - I'll still have to use my 30W hand iron. (Sorry if the question is stupid but as I said I'm a noob)

Comment: Another thing I'm wondering then is if I could simply tape wires from the controller pins to my arduino board and work with the flash while still being soldered on the board. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD -- desoldering will not necessarily destroy it.   Desoldering with an SMD with a hand iron very likely will.  Have you ever desoldered an SMD with a hand iron before?  I'd question whether your results will even be suitable for remounting, let alone functional.  As to the taping wires thing -- I'd need to see real plans for what you're envisioning.

Comment: Well it's quite simple idea actually - instead of desoldering and connecting to a new circuit - I'll connect wires directly from the new circuit to the SMD on board. And I'll try to tape the wires to the pins instead of using solder (as a temporary solution - so I can flash the memory). Will this create any problems?

Comment: By the way the board where SMD is already soldered is working and using it. I just want to read/write to it for some time.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD -- yes, it certainly could, any way from bad connections to shorts to killing chips its attached to to just plain old not working because pins are tied to logic levels, but it depends on your EXACT implementation, which we won't know without a circuit diagram.  I wouldn't ask for more info unless I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

The answers made by Peter and Scott are valid.
Adding to this that you consider yourself a Noob, I strongly advise against desoldering the component as it does imply risks that you will not be able to resolder it.

An alternative is that you leave the component on the board, but in order to read/change its contents, you simply solder wires on the pins which you connect to your Arduino.
You "just" have to ensure that nothing on your original board is driving the pins.
To do so you may need to power just your SPI flash and not the board.  You may need to separate the power supply to your SPI flash from the rest of the board. That may be possible by cutting the power trace on the PCB and fix that later or by lifting the power pin of the memory or whatever is possible with the orignal board and your competence.

I personnally find it easier to solder a few wires to a component than solder it off and on again.

Comment: Are you sure this way nothing will go wrong? I was told that this could potentially power the board where the chip is soldered or even fry it. And btw I was thinking the same thing from sometime though I was lead to believe that taping the wires would be more safe in the case.

Comment: 1. This is why I suggest to make sure to separate the SPI Memory power from the rest of the board (GND can remain connected).
2. I do not know what you mean by taping the wires.  Taping the wires to isolate them will be difficult.  Taping the wires (together) to the board to limit mechanical movement of the solder points is recommended.
3. I've recently done something similar during development to check that the peripherals of the system were responding ok before the microcontroller firmware was mature enough.
Verify the connections you made (and unmade) with a multimeter before power up.

Comment: I just read that you mention "taping" in your comment on Scott's response.
So you do seem to refer to applying a tape to make contact.
This seems to be used only for the bigger wired connections where you can twist the wires together and put a tape around it - something I have applied in the past to wires.
Doing so for such a small componant is calling for trouble: the wires will move, stop making contact and - worst case - make contact and short-circuits that might even be destructive.

One more tip: improve your soldering skills on a another board that you no longer require.

Comment: So you mean if I "separate the SPI Memory power from the rest of the board" - all other pins connected both to the original pcb and the arduino (as only the arduino operating) won't create any problems (like for example damaging my original pcb) right?

Comment: Wouldn't the digital signals be a problem too when connected to both the Arduino and the original pcb board or else why not?

Comment: When you only power the SPI Memory power, the worst that can happen is that part of the circuit is powered from the other pins of your SPI Memory, but they can not provide a lot of drive anyway.   ***   Generally when a microcontroller is not powered, its digital pins are in "tristate" or input mode  ***  That is also the reason why powering your digital pins from the arduino while only the SPI Memory is powers, should not be an issue  ***  Nothing is 100% sure without having 100% of the information, but this looks much safer than desoldering the component completely.